# Promises with Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I want a Character class, inheriting from MonoBehavior and exposing handfuls methods : Walk, Attack, ...

However, assuming that two components use these methods at the same time, I would like to queue the actions and have some way to notify the components that their actions have been executed.

In Javascript standard, I would have done something like this :

```
var Character = function ( ) {
    this._deferred = new Deferred( );
};

Character.prototype.walk = function ( ) {
    return this._deferred = this._deferred.then( function ( ) {
        // Do the actual walk
    } );
};

Character.prototype.attack = function ( ) {
    return this._deferred = this._deferred.then( function ( ) {
        // Do the actual attack
    } );
};

var character = new Character( );

// Component A
character.walk( ).then( function ( ) {
    // Executes when the walk is done
} );

// Component B
character.attack( ).then( function ( ) {
    // Executes when the walk AND attack is done
} );
```

What is the right way to do so with Unity / C# ?

Comment: It's unclear. Are you looking for Promises implementation in C#? Or do you want a way to queue character's commands? Answering "both" means that you are trying to solve the problem with wrong instruments.

Comment: Take a look at Action<>, Function<>, maybe delegate

Comment: @SergeyKrusch My question is about the "Unity way" to chain commands. In Javascript I would probably use something like Promises, but maybe it's the wrong track in a Unity world.

Answer (score 5):

## Preamble

1. For the answer I will use this "I would like to queue the actions" as a description of your problem.
2. There are lot of ways to solve this problem. And I don't pretend to be comprehensive.
3. Even in JS I would consider using Promises for queuing character commands as wrong choice.
4. I haven't ever compiled, run or tested the code that i present here :D

## Promises in C#

There is [some C# port of Promises](https://gist.github.com/cuppster/3612000) on github. I haven't ever used it, but the code doesn't seem to contain anything that stops it from being used in Unity. Anyway, you can give it a try.

## Using [Queue<>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7977ey2c%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

I would definitely use `Queue<TCommand>` of some TCommand for this problem. The only question is what to use as TCommand. I will give you 2 examples here. But, as usual, there are more options.

### Some class

Something like this:

```
public enum CommandUpdateResult
{
    Ongoing,
    Finished
}

public interface ICommand
{
   CommandUpdateResult Update();
}

public class RunCommand: ICommand
{
    // Bla-bla-bla
}

public class AttackCommand: ICommand
{
    // Bla-bla-bla
}


public class Character: MonoBehaviour
{
    private Queue<ICommand> commandQueue;

    public void Awake()
    {
        commandQueue = new Queue<ICommand>();
    }

    public void Update()
    {
        if (commandQueue.Count > 0 && commandQueue.Peek().Update() == CommandUpdateResult.Finished)
            commandQueue.Dequeue();
    }

    public void EnqueueCommand(ICommand command)
    {
        commandQueue.Enqueue(command);
    }
}

public class SomeClassThatUsesCharacter
{
    private Character character;
    public void SomeMethodThatUsesCharacter()
    {
        character.EnqueueCommand(new RunCommand(bla-bla-bla));
        character.EnqueueCommand(new AttackCommand(bla-bla-bla));
    }
}
```

### IEnumerator

The simplest (but not very elegant) way to use IEnumerator is to use it with some infinite [coroutine](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/Coroutines.html).

```
public class Character: MonoBehaviour
{
    private Queue<IEnumerator> commandQueue;

    private IEnumerator CommandQueueCoroutine()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if (commandQueue.Count > 0)
                yield return StartCoroutine(commandQueue.Peek());
            else
                yield return new WaitForFixedUpdate();
        }
    }

    public void Awake()
    {
        commandQueue = new Queue<ICommand>();
        StartCoroutine(CommandQueueCoroutine());
    }

    public void Update()
    {
        if (commandQueue.Count > 0 && commandQueue.Peek().Update() == CommandUpdateResult.Finished)
            commandQueue.Dequeue();
    }

    public void Enqueue(IEnumerator command)
    {
        commandQueue.Enqueue(command);
    }

    IEnumerator RunCommand()
    {
        while (Jenny.Tells("Run"))
        {
            transform.position.x += 1;
            yield return new WaitForFixedUpdate();
        }
    }

    IEnumerator AttackCommand(BadGuy badGuy)
    {
        badGuy.Die();
        yield break;
    }
}

public class SomeClassThatUsesCharacter
{
    private Character character;

    public void SomeMethodThatUsesCharacter()
    {
        character.Enqueue(character.RunCommand());
        character.Enqueue(character.AttackCommand(someBadGuy));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A very good Unity Promise library: https://github.com/Real-Serious-Games/C-Sharp-Promise and see related blog http://www.what-could-possibly-go-wrong.com/promises-for-game-development/

Alternatively I think you can also go down an RX approach with Observers that react to `Walk` and `Attack` events. See https://github.com/neuecc/UniRx

Answer (score 0):

Well, at the moment Unity already allows you to use:

- TaskCompletionSource as a promise;
- Task as a future;

but if Promise itself is more suitable for your project give it a try by using: [C-Sharp-Cancellable-Promise library](https://github.com/AlexeyPerov/C-Sharp-Cancellable-Promise)

This is a fork of [Real-Serious-Games Promise lib](https://github.com/Real-Serious-Games/C-Sharp-Promise) updated to the latest .NET and **with Promises cancellation support.**